# Ruby Hash explanation

Tags: ruby, hash

I do not understand this particular step in CodeAcademy.

```
text = puts "Hello text please"
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split(' ')
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |x| frequencies[x] += 1 }
```

The idea is to filter the input to return a hash with each word and the amount of times the word appears. Having trouble understanding why this works.

```
words.each { |x| frequencies[x] += 1 }
```

Doesn't hash work by a `{key, value}` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for setting hash value is:

```
hash_name[key] = value
```

And the value is referenced as `hash_name[key]`. So:

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
```

This creates a new hash which, if you read the value of the hash for an unknown key, it will allow it and default the key's value as `0` (returns a `0`). Without the `0` parameter, there would be no default key value, so that reading the hash with an unknown key would yield `nil`. But with the default return value of `0`, the following:

```
words.each { |x| frequencies[x] += 1 }
```

Takes advantage of the default by going through all of the words, using them as keys, even though they don't initially exist, and incrementing the hash value of `frequency[x]` for the hash key `x` (the current word). If it hasn't been set yet, it starts at `0` which is what you want to count things. This because `+=` will really mean `frequencies[x] = frequencies[x] + 1` and the initial value returned for `frequencies[x]` when the value hasn't been set yet will be `0`.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that things like `h = Hash.new(0); puts h['pancakes']` don't mean that `h` now has a `'pancakes'` key. The code in question quietly gets around this because `f[x] += 1` is actually `f[x] = f[x] + 1` so the partially hidden assignment triggers the creation of the `x` key.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, that is true and I didn't make that totally clear. I'll update accordingly. Thanks for highlighting that fact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly where your problem lies, but hopefully this will help.

> Doesn't hash work by a {key, value} method?

Yes it does. In the line

```
words.each { |x| frequencies[x] += 1 }
```

the hash is called `frequencies` and the key is `x`. The value for that key is returned by the expression `frequencies[x]`.

It's just like an array, but using strings as indices instead of integers. `data[2]` is the value stored at the element of array `data` identified by `2`, while `frequencies[x]` is the value stored at the element of hash `frequencies` indicated by `x`.

`+=` has its usual meaning as a Ruby abbreviation, so that `var += 1` is identical to `var  = var + 1`.

So `frequencies[x] += 1` is `frequencies[x] = frequencies[x] + 1`: it adds one to the current value of the hash element identified by `x`.

The last piece in the puzzle is the way `frequencies` has been created. Ordinarily, accessing a hash element that hasn't been assigned returns `nil`. Using `+=` would usually raise an `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` error because there is no method `NilClass#+`. But using `Hash.new(0)` creates a hash with a *default value* of zero, so that non-existent elements of this hash evaluate as `0` instead of `nil`, and now everything works fine when you try to increment an element for the first time.